# task not serializable spark REPL

Tags: apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

another basics going wrong

I am trying to read a file in spark context and skip the header of the file by doing this

```
scala> val read = sc.textFile("/user/edureka/data/ls2014.tsv")
scala> val header = read.first
scala> val data = read.filter(row => (row != header))
```

with these I get error "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable".

how does serialization work in this scenario.. want to know the basic and why it is erroring here.

note: I know there other methods to skip the header of the file. I however would like to know the concept of serialization in this context. Please share your views.

Answer (score 0):

You have row, where I assume you mean rec:

```
val restfile = read.map(rec => row != header)
```

Should be this:

```
val restfile = read.map(rec => rec != header)
```

Probably row is something you defined earlier in the repl that isn't serializable, and therefore can not be automatically passed to the executors via the closure.

Comment: I apologize. It was a typo..I did not mean to add row..it is "rec"

Comment: I get the error while
scala > val restfile = read.map(rec => rec != header)

Comment: You corrected code works for me w/ a random text file.  Also I am assuming you mean filter not map?  map will convert every row to either True or False

Comment: yes you are correct. I have been trying all sorts of possibilities. The "filter" is what is giving error.sorry about that. Were you able to run filter? or can we not use filter? how does that lead to serialization error

Comment: how are you using the filter ? can you update the question?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing that error... Neither should cause a serialization error based upon the code you've posted.  That would only happen if you referenced an object that wasn't serializeable inside the function you are running on the executor (passed to filter/map) because spark will automatically attempt to send that object to the executor for you.

Comment: I have updated the exact code. Hope this helps. I have re-run the code. I get the same error